# Using Eclipse - No option to run or debug PHP as a script?

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug, eclipse-pdt, zend-debugger

I wanted to try pick up PHP again and decided to try out Eclipse as well.

I've just done a fresh install of Eclipse PDT, as well as the relevant php/mysql/apache servers with EasyPHP. Zend-debugger and Xdebug have also been installed.

However, I don't have an option to Run or Debug as a PHP script. The only option available is to Run As a "PHP Web Application". I've seen guides and videos that refers to a Run As PHP Script option, but I don't have that.

What do I need to configure to get this?

Comment: You should find 'PHP CLI Application' in Run/Debug configuration dialog if you correctly installed PDT.

Comment: Thanks. The comment gave me a hint. I just had to enable to CLI debug option (Window->Preferences->PHP->Debug->check "Enable CLI Debug")

Answer (score 0):

same problem here  i choose run as > run configurations > on the left there is php cli application  double click on it to create new then choose alternate php and from it set the directory for your php executable which i found in /usr/bin/php5 and php.ini the browse to your php file to run it 
the problem here is that you'll have to set the the directory for the php script file each time you run a new script

hope this will help